# Format python code in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, ide, format, spyder

Can anyone please advice the key combination to format python code in annaconda/Spyder IDE? In Eclipse IDE when coding in Java I usually use command F, however in Spyder IDEthe key combination causes search window to pop up.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this

> Source -> Fix Indentation, Remove Trailing Spaces

This is not the most efficient way, but it seems there are no key combinations to do these. Even in preferences, they have not allowed to add new shortcut for this.